# ¿Porque me duplica los registros al hacer una consulta a diferentes tablas con INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysqldb

Al hacer un consulta en 3 tablas utilizando el INNER JOIN comparando los números de cedula me duplica cada registro, mostrando en la consulta dos veces cada ID por ende dos veces cada fecha de entrada y salida como se muestra a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que utilice es:

```sql
SELECT registro_empleado.IdRegEmpleado, registrosalida.idRegistroSalida, 
empleado.ApellidoEmp,  registro_empleado.FechaIng,  registrosalida.FechaSal2  
FROM empleado 
  INNER JOIN registrosalida 
  ON registrosalida.CedulaRS = empleado.CedulaEmp 
  INNER JOIN registro_empleado 
  ON registro_empleado.NumCedula = empleado.CedulaEmp 
ORDER BY ApellidoEmp ASC;
```

Como debería debe de quedar es así:

| ID1 | ID2 | APELLIDO | FechaEntrada | FechaSalida |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | 123 | Abello Alvarez | 2022/6/27 6:0:10 | 2022/6/27 18:27:2242 |
| 300 | 493 | Abello Alvarez | 2022/6/28 17:54:33 | 2022/6/29 6:27:46 |
| 492 | null | Abello Alvarez | 2022/6/29 17:35:18 | null |

Solo mostrando la entrada y salida por turno

Comment: Ningún registro se está repitiendo... ¿a qué te refieres exactamente?

Comment: Los ID están mostrando los registros repetidos, por ejemplo en IdRegEmpleado esta el 300 dos veces al igual que el 42 y 492

Comment: Ahhh, claro, pero eso no se llaman registros repetidos, tienen valores únicos, p.ej. El ID 300 en una fila tiene ID 300, 123 y en otra tiene ID 300, 493; tú qué deseas? que no se muestren qué valores? o que se muestre el mayor de todos los ID 300 ? o algo así?

Comment: ``INNER JOIN`` es el producto cruzado de dos o mas tablas, si quieres resultados que no se repitan deberías usar ``LEFT JOIN``.

Comment: Que no se repitan los registros, cada ID cuenta con una fecha de entrada y una salida entonces esta repitiendo la misma información dos veces

Comment: Ya intente con LEFT JOIN y tampoco da

Comment: Solo deseas mostrar las fechas de entrada y salida? Si es así entonces quita los campos extra como el IdRegEmpleado y haces un `GROUP BY` y ahí ya estaría.

Comment: Solo un detalle que veo es que por ejemplo en el ID 300, 123 tiene una fecha de salida distinta a la ID 300,493; nuevamente, los registros no se están repitiendo.

Comment: Dos problemas: A) no nos muestras los datos en las tablas que usas. El resultado dice que no hay repetición de datos como se espera. B) No dices cuál es la salida esperada a partir de esos datos de prueba. La consulta hace lo que le dices que haga, pero sin esta info que te indico, no vas a obtener lo que deseas realmente. Ve a [edit] la pregunta

Comment: Ya lo repetí y coloque como debería de quedar, no se si así me haga entender, muchas gracias